# return integer value of random string key

Tags: java, random, hashmap, key-value

This is my BlackJack project and it currently only returns 1 card. I am struggling to get the randomKey to be equal to its value in the HashMap

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random ran = new Random();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    HashMap<String, Integer> hash = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hash.put("2", 2);
    hash.put("3", 3);
    hash.put("4", 4);
    hash.put("5", 5);
    hash.put("6", 6);
    hash.put("7", 7);
    hash.put("8", 8);
    hash.put("9", 9);
    hash.put("10", 10);
    hash.put("Jack", 10);
    hash.put("Queen", 10);
    hash.put("King", 10);
    hash.put("Ace", 11);

    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<>(hash.keySet());
    List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<>(hash.values());


    String[] colors = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        int col = ran.nextInt(colors.length); // random color
        String randomKey = keyList.get(ran.nextInt(hash.size())); // random type
        int keyValue = valueList.get(ran.nextInt(hash.size())); 

        System.out.println(randomKey+ " of "+colors[col]);
        if (keyValue < 21) {System.out.println(keyValue);}
    } // returns a cards
```

I used the `if (keyValue < 21) {System.out.println(keyValue);}` to test if the
keyValue would be equal to the unique value of the random key. Obviously it isnt, but I need it to be so I can then calculate the sum of multiple cards, while printing out only the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these two lines:

```
    String randomKey = keyList.get(ran.nextInt(hash.size())); // random type
    int keyValue = valueList.get(ran.nextInt(hash.size()));
```

you choose two (different) random numbers, and use those to get a key and a value. Since both calls to `ran` are independent, there's nothing to force the generated value to correspond to the generated key. I think what you mean to do is to get a random number to choose a random card, then use the `HashMap` to lookup the value corresponding to the chosen card.

```
    String randomKey = keyList.get(ran.nextInt(hash.size())); // random type
    int keyValue = hash.get(randomKey);
```

You could tell you're on the wrong track because in the provided code, you never read from `hash`.